# React-admin : Remove or add a custom toolbar in SimpleForm

Tags: react-admin

How can I **remove default toolbar** and add a **custom toolbar** as per my requirements and not get the default Save button with Floppy Disk in **SimpleForm**?

I am able to style the buttons and remove the icons on the toolbar but not able to proceed further as I am new to react-admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation : [React-Admin Toolbar](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.8/CreateEdit.html#toolbar), you can always override the default layout of the toolbar with `toolbar={<CustomToolbarComponent />}` props in the SimpleForm component.

As for disabling the toolbar altogether, you can use `toolbar={false}` in SimpleForm and that would remove it.

You can also let toolbar be false, and maybe add the CustomToolbarComponent inside the SimpleForm component.

Something like :

```
<SimpleForm toolbar={false}>
     <FormComponent1 />
     <FormComponent2 />
     <CustomToolbarComponent />
</SimpleForm>
```

As someone who was new to react-admin a few weeks ago too, please read the documentation thouroughly and their code and play with it, you'll come across the solution.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Also, a tip : Use admin's Toolbar component over Material-UI because even though its built on Material UI only, but has support for mobile and is responsive.